# powershell script posting to api

Tags: windows, powershell

I've got an api that I'm trying to put data to. It creates a ticket in our ticketing system. The example code that I got from the api docs is a curl statement and works perfect in linux as is (in a terminal), but I'm trying to do it in powershell (for windows machines), but it just is not working. I've found out that (in PS => 3) curl is actually "Invoke-RestMethod", I've also tried specifically curl.exe and even ended up downloading and installing curl and that doesn't work. Here's the unedited curl script that our ticketing system gave us...

```
curl -X POST "https://sample.com/api/v1/tickets" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer 1234512345123451234512345" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"customer_id\":999999999,\"subject\":\"ticket name\",\"problem_type\":\"string\",\"status\":\"New\",\"comments_attributes\":[{\"subject\":\"comment subject\",\"body\":\"computerhostname - E: - 10%\",\"hidden\":true,\"do_not_email\":true,\"tech\":\"johnny rockets\"}]}"
```

I've worked for hours on it and I've tried to parse it out into something that will work for Invoke-RestMethod, and this is what I'm down to...

```
$e = @{
    method = "Post"
    uri = "https://sample.com/api/v1/tickets"
    headers = @{
        "accept" = "application/json"
        "Authorization" = "Bearer 1234512345123451234512345"
        "Content-Type" = "application/json"
        }
    body = @{
        "customer_id" = "999999999"
        "subject" = "ticket name"
        "problem_type" = ""
        "status" = "New"
        "comments_attributes" = @{
            "subject" = "comment subject"
            "body" = "computerhostname - e: - 10%"
            "hidden" = "true"
            "do_not_email" = true"
            "tech" = "johnny rockets"
            }
    }
        
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod @e
```

But I get I'm receiving errors still, here's what I receive...

```
At C:\Users\rot\Desktop\ticketpostscript.ps1:19 char:28
+             "tech" = "johnny rockets"
+                                     ~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
At C:\Users\rot\Desktop\ticketpostscript.ps1:25 char:33
+ $response = Invoke-RestMethod @e
+                                 ~
The hash literal was incomplete.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

I feel like I'm missing something dumb, but I can't spot it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The line right above `"subject" = ...` has `"{` - should probably be `@{`. There's a corresponding `"` after the closing `}` as well, remove that

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - You got me further along I think. Sorry I feel like a total noob, but it appears that I should edit original post with new information right? I edited it with the changes you suggested and the new errors. Thanks

Comment: Line above `"tech" = ...` is missing a `"` in front of `true` (I'd suggest using boolean literals `$true` and `$false` in place of `"true"` or `"false"` btw). Do yourself a favor and edit your code in an editor with PowerShell syntax highlighting - PowerShell ISE or VSCode with the PowerShell extension will do

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - yes, thank you, what a silly mistake. I was using visual studio code, and I didn't even recognize that it was pointing that out. I'm still getting an error, but it's the remote server returning an error "bad request", so I'll have to talk with them about that part. Thank you for you super quick help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Mathias ( @MathiasR.Jessen ) was able to point out that I had missed a little punctuation here and there. The final code that worked is...

```
$e = @{
    method = "Post"
    uri = "https://sample.com/api/v1/tickets"
    headers = @{
        "accept" = "application/json"
        "Authorization" = "Bearer 1234512345123451234512345"
        "Content-Type" = "application/json"
        }
    body = @{
        "customer_id" = "999999999"
        "subject" = "ticket name"
        "problem_type" = ""
        "status" = "New"
        "comments_attributes" = @{
            "subject" = "comment subject"
            "body" = "computerhostname - e: - 10%"
            "hidden" = "true"
            "do_not_email" = "true"
            "tech" = "johnny rockets"
            }
        }
        
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod @e
```